# Vite React VScode. Errors not underlined, no warnings etc

Tags: visual-studio-code, vite

I've just started assembling my projects with Vite. And noticed that VSCode doesn't inform you about your mistakes anymore. Component just doesn't work properly and I don't see any underlines. So I did something like this:

```
const BasketItem = ({ removeFrromOrder, id, name, price, quantity }) => {
  return (
    <ListItem>
      <Typography variant='body1'>
        {name} {price}руб x{quantity}
      </Typography>

      <IconButton onClick={() => removeFrromOrder(id)}>
        <Close />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

```
<BasketItem key={item.name} removeFromOrder={removeFromOrder} {...item} />
```

Nothing is underlined. Usually the last string of code would be underlined since component expects removeFrromOrder with two 'r' (which is typo :)
Any ideas why it would be happening? Is it connected with Vite in any way?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you need to do is add a "jsconfig.json" file to your project folder. The "jsconfig.json" file should contain the following lines:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "checkJs": true,
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```